# Docker Selenium standalone server is Unable to upload a file to the grid browser in the container

Tags: java, docker, selenium

I have a selenium script that to upload an attachment runs on maven and java and is working fine when run from Local.

When I run it on docker container using selenium standalone server receiving the following exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found :
```

Not sure how to resolve it inside the container, I have verified the file is available

The docker compose file Iam using is as follows:

```
    version : '3'
services :
  maven:
    container_name : Maven-Java
    image : maven:3.5.3-jdk-8-alpine
    volumes :
      - .:/workspace
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    depends_on :
      - selenium
    command : mvn -f /workspace test
  selenium:
    container_name : selenium
    image : selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports :
      - 4444:4444
```

Comment: You say you have verified the file is available. Have you verified the file is available **inside the docker container**?

Comment: I printed the files that are available in that specific location. And from logs verified the file is available but the driver is unable to upload.

Comment: What you mean by run it on a docker container ? Docker container as the hub ?

Comment: Docker container file system is isolated from host system. So you cannot just run your script in docker and expect it will access anything you have at your host. You need to mount a folder on your host to a folder inside the container or copy the file to container file system (both options are taken when build an image to run).

Comment: @PDHide, I ran in docker using the selenium stand alone chrome you can find the related info here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#standalone

Comment: @AlexeyR. you are correct and yes I also did a volume mapping where I have mapped my required folder to the container, and to check if all the files are available I have printed the files that are in folders into logs and verified the required files are available and I am sure this issue is more related to selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mounted the volume to container where your test code is running. However you need to mount the volume to the container where the browser is running.

The thing is that when your code says to the web app "hey, this is the file that you need to upload", the test code sends not a file itself but a path that is passed to the browser. Then browser tries to look up that file and build appropriate request to the server.

So the file hast to be within the container where the browser is running.

Comment: the browser is launched by the container using the selenium grid and as you can see above I have mapped my test script folder to the selenium container, All other tests are running except of the uploading a file so i'm thinking this is more of a selenium issue than of docker

Comment: No you didn't map. You mapped it to `container_name : Maven-Java`. Not to `container_name : selenium`.

Comment: Ok Got your point now, But will I be able to map the same folder to multiple containers @Alexey R.

Comment: I believe you will

Comment: Thanks @Alexey R, You are right it worked for me, Also found an alternative with out mapping the volumes

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a path configuration.
Create a file browsers.json
add this script there

```json
{
  "chrome": {
        "default": "85.0",
        "versions": {
            "85.0": {
                "image": "selenoid/vnc:chrome_85.0",
                "port": "4444",
                "volumes": ["/home/ubuntu/your-project:/opt/docker"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and run with this `--browsers-json browsers.json` argument

this example is for selenoid, but if you don't use selenoid, just add `"volumes": ["/home/ubuntu/your-project:/opt/docker"]` to your selenium grid config.

Comment: No, Iam not using Selenoid, and iam using windows in my host so and in the docker container using the chrome standalone server to run so, not sure about the volume mapping

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for the answer's so the working solution I found are two one is as @Alexey mentioned I should also volume map my script folder to the selenium container as well as below:

```
selenium:
   volumes :
     - .:/workspace
```

Above is a docker oriented solution,  the other one I found is with selenium grid where the grid can detect the files using a file detector, it can be done by adding the following snipet.

```
remoteDriver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

Both the solutions are working and have solved my problem.